# Error when calling Azure Powershell New-AzResource: request content invalid

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell

I am stuck on this Azure PowerShell error when calling New-AzResource:

> new-azresource : InvalidRequestContent : The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Could not find member 'dependsOn' on object of type 'ResourceProxyDefinition'. Path 'dependsOn'.'.

The object I pass into the -property argument of New-AzResource is indeed an object with a dependsOn property. So the message is a decoy. And, of course, it works just fine in the CLI.

Interestingly, you cannot even find that message, or the substring ResourceProxyDefinition in any of the code for the Az PS module (https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell). I have researched this to the extent I can think of, like looking at the underlyzing Azure API and source code. Try a Google search for ResourceProxyDefinition (no spaces) and you will mostly land on a GitHub issue I hijacked.

For the property object, I start from a json template (given below, partially). That JSON works directly in the CLI. However, for the azure powershell module, I use `ConvertFrom-Json` on the file contents and pass the resulting object as the argument.

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.VirtualMachineImages/imageTemplates",
  "apiVersion": "2019-05-01-preview",
  "location": "eastus2",
  "dependsOn": [],
  "tags": {
    "imagebuilderTemplate": "My.WindowsServer.2019-Datacenter-1910020354.tpl"
  },

  "properties": {
    "buildTimeoutInMinutes": 100,

    "source": {
      "type": "PlatformImage",
      "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
      "offer": "WindowsServer",
      "sku": "2019-Datacenter",
      "version": "2019.0.20190603"
    },
```

Comment: Try `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment`, refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @JoyWang. I am having a hard time coming up with the right template to drive Azure Image Builder. New-AzResourceGroupDeployment also complains about not being able to find things. It appears to not be the same as the template you give to the az CLI to do the same operation. I cannot find any relevant examples here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates . And, no documentation either. Having a hard time with trial and error, as the error message from the validation is just wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some changes to your template to be like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "resources": [
    {
    "name": "My.WindowsServer.2019-Datacenter-1910030425.tpl",
    "type": "Microsoft.VirtualMachineImages/imageTemplates",
    "apiVersion": "2019-05-01-preview",
    "location": "eastus2",
    "dependsOn": [],
    "tags": {
      "imagebuilderTemplate": "My.WindowsServer.2019-Datacenter-1910030425.tpl"
    },

    "properties": {
      "buildTimeoutInMinutes": 100,
      "source": {
        "type": "PlatformImage",
        "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
        "offer": "WindowsServer",
        "sku": "2019-Datacenter",
        "version": "2019.0.20190603"
```

which includes adding an extra level (nesting the previous template under "resources" and adding a "$schema" and "contentVersion" you are set for deployment.

Now, use:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $imageResourceGroup  `
    -TemplateFile $imageTemplateFile
```

which will read in the JSON file and it works! Don't use New-AzResource.